# How to make JavaFX ColorPicker disabled without dim appearence?

Tags: javafx-2, color-picker

I've been trying to disable a `javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker` without dimming it in my UI. Meaning that I want it to look as enabled (enabled appearence), but just do not respond to any command, also not showing the table of colors on mouse click (actually disabled). This behaviour will be interchangeable with normal behaviour, according to the system state (i.e., sometimes color picker will behave as normal).

I've tried some options, but none seemed to work, as follows:

**1. Use `setEditable(boolean)`:**

```
myColorPicker.setEditable(false);
```

This just doesn't work, the color picker remains editable.

**2. Use `setDisable(boolean)` and `setOpacity(double)` together:**

```
myColorPicker.setDisable(true);
myColorPicker.setOpacity(1.0f);
```

This makes the color picker actually not editable, and the resulting color picker appear a little less dimmed than just using `setDisable(true)`, but still not the appearence of an enabled color picker.

**3. Overriding `onMouseClick()`, `onMousePressed()` and `onMouseReleased()` with empty implementations:**

```
myColorPicker.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler <MouseEvent>() {
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Mouse clicked.");
    }
});

myColorPicker.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler <MouseEvent>() {
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Mouse pressed.");
    }
});

myColorPicker.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler <MouseEvent>() {
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Mouse released.");
    }
});
```

The above approach printed on my console the corresponding messages, but color picker still responded to mouse click (showing the color table and allowing to pick a new color). Also tried to override `setOnAction(EventHandler<ActionEvent>)`, but with same effect (except that no console printing when I clicked the color picker).

Here it is the excerpt of my FXML:

```
<VBox fx:controller="mypackage.ElementConfigWidget"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:id="root" styleClass="elementConfigPane">
    <HBox id="elementInfo">
        (...)
        <ColorPicker fx:id="elementColor" styleClass="elementColor" />
    </HBox>
(...)
</VBox>
```

Here it is my CSS exerpt:

```
.elementColor {
    -fx-cursor: hand;
    -fx-background-color: #fff;
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-pref-width: 50.0;
}
```

I actually expected `setEditable(boolean)` to solve my problem, by keeping the element appearence and ignoring input actions. What am I missing?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage to achieve it with some CSS 
.Also you need to setDisable(true) and opacity to 1.0

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        ColorPicker myColorPicker = new ColorPicker();

        myColorPicker.setDisable(true);
        myColorPicker.setOpacity(1.0);

        Scene s = new Scene(myColorPicker);
        s.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("test.css").toExternalForm());

        primaryStage.setScene(s);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

And the test.css

```
.color-picker > .label:disabled {
    -fx-opacity : 1.0;
}
```